# Using script type=template within a HTML?

Tags: html, templates

I've stumbled upon a very odd html markup while following an tutorial online, where the author is using type="template" within his script tag. Within the markups he also uses double brackets....which I have no clues at all.

```
<script id="template" type="template">
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  <img src="{{imgSrc}}" alt="{{title}}" />
</script>
```

I've tried google it but nothing turns up, is it some kind of html preprocessors?

Comment: Is this in a php, or some other server processed file?

Comment: @Lance, no the author is using a plain html file and the tutorial is about javascript pushState

Comment: Then I have no clue.  Unless it is just a non-functioning example.

Comment: I'm curious to see what the answer ends up being.

Comment: by the way here is the link to the tutorial that is using this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXLShnZTtGo

Comment: Did you see my answer, below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the answer, it is actually a way of creating a custom Javascript template but is not as complicated as jquery-template, handlebars and mustache.

Using script type=template is just a way of tricking the browser that it is not a valid markup and hence the browser will just ignore it, however we can still process it using javascript.

You can read more about it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEAG3v3ozlc

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found it!

It's AngularJS.

https://angularjs.org/

Comment: Actually I just found the answer you can check my post below

Comment: Yeah, but the {{ something }} are AngularJS.